# Java UML editable component/lib

Tags: java, xml, uml

I have a task where we need to generate UML(or similar) from XML and will be able to edit text, property type and drag dependency row. But I can't find any Java lib or component wich will allow me to do such.
For example [PlantText](https://www.planttext.com/) is a good lib  but it does not allow to make edit.

If someone known such lib/compoment please share.
Thanks

EDIT:
Sorry, maybe I wasn't wrote clear. Actually, I need library which I can implement into my project, and after I will be able to generate UML from my project, then edit it and save into XML.

Comment: What kind of XML is it?  Is it custom?  Are you talking about XML for the UML standard produced by OMG.  http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock sorry, a wasn't be so clear. Please review the EDIT section

Answer (score 0):

[draw.io](http://draw.io) is very good site where you can create (not only) UML's and save them to XML file so in future you can edit it. The drawback is it is not automatic and must be drawn from scratch.

Comment: sorry, a wasn't be so clear. Please review the EDIT section. I need lib for generating/editing UML which I can integrate into my project.